# Increasing data attribute on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

What I'm attempting seems simple enough, but I'm obviously missing something. I have a simple select menu. After selecting a country, the value is passed into a variable, prepended with a hash to change it modify it to the respected `id`. Using this `id` I'm attempting to increase the `data-size` by 1.  The only issue is that nothing happens with the `data-size`.

Here's a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5JU85/)**.

Things should flow like this:

1. Select country
2. Select value turned into `id` tag
3. `data-size` of said `id` is increased by 1 in the HTML

**EDIT/UPDATE**

I need the actual `data-size` value to be updated in the HTML because I have specific CSS that deals with different values.

**HTML**

```
<select name="countryList" id="countryList" class="selectBox">
    <option value="" disabled selected>SELECT</option>
    <option value="austria">Austria</option>
    <option value="brazil">Brazil</option>
    <option value="canada">Canada</option>
</select>
<button class="cancel">cancel</button>
<button class="confirm">confirm</button>

<div class="dot" data-size="0" id="austria"></div>
<div class="dot" data-size="0" id="brazil"></div>
<div class="dot" data-size="0" id="canada"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var countryPicked = "";

$('.confirm').on(touchClick, function(){
    countryPicked = $('#countryList').val();
    countryPicked = ($('#' + countryPicked));
    var i = countryPicked.data('size');
    countryPicked.data('size', i + 1);
});
```

Comment: Does the function get called? Is the data attribute read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `touchClick` to `"click"`

The DOM will not be changed **visibly**, because it is stored internally.

use `attr('data-size',i + 1)` if you want the DOM to be updated

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/5JU85/2/)

Comment: Maybe you can explain why the DOM doesn't get changed?

Comment: @Kapi, yeah, I explained it. Thanks BTW

Comment: i have to use touchClick because it's a web app being built for a touchscreen.

Comment: So, properly your code already works but you couldn't verify it correctly? Try to use an alert like Amit Joki did in his JSFiddle to verify if the data-size increases each touchClick.

Comment: @AmitJoki Sorry, I should have described my issue better, I've made an edit. I need the `DOM` to be updated because I have CSS that deals with different values.

Comment: @BadDog, I've answered

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
countryPicked.attr('data-size', i+1);
```

There seems to be something wrong with .data(), it can only READ the property, not SET it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please modify the handler to:

```
$('.confirm').on(`click`, function(){
   //code here
});
```

For multiple events, give comma separated value as event.

Also note that changes will not be reflected in console. However you can check them using `alert` or `console.log`

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5JU85/3/)**

jQuery stores the data internally if they don't exist the first time you set them. If you really want to force it:

```
countryPicked.attr('data-size', i + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GtT3Q/13/

```
$('.confirm').click(function(){
   var countryPicked = $('#countryList').val();
   countryPicked = $('#' + countryPicked);
   var i = parseInt(countryPicked.attr('data-size'));
   countryPicked.attr('data-size', i + 1);
});
```